# Is the child of a mamzer and a convert mamzer?

Tags: mamzer

If a mamzer or mamzeret marries a convert, do the children born to them acquire the status of mamzer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 4:18

> יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁנָּשָׂא מַמְזֶרֶת, אוֹ מַמְזֵר שֶׁנָּשָׂא יִשְׂרְאֵלִית, הַוָּלָד מַמְזֵר לְעוֹלָם:

Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 4:19

> גּוֹי וְעֶבֶד שֶׁבָּאוּ עַל הַמַּמְזֶרֶת, הַוָּלָד מַמְזֵר. וְאִם בָּאוּ עַל בַּת יִשְׂרָאֵל, בֵּין פְּנוּיָה בֵּין אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ, הַוָּלָד כָּשֵׁר, וּפָגוּם לִכְהֻנָּה:

Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 4:22

> גֵּר וְעֶבֶד מְשֻׁחְרָר, מֻתָּרִים בְּמַמְזֶרֶת, וְכֵן מַמְזֵר מֻתָּר בְּגִיּוֹרֶת וּבִמְשֻׁחְרֶרֶת, מִשּׁוּם דִּקְהַל גֵּרִים לֹא אִקְּרֵי קָהָל, וְהַוָּלָד מַמְזֵר. וַאֲפִלּוּ הָיְתָה הוֹרָתוֹ וְלֵידָתוֹ בִּקְדֻשָּׁה, כְּגוֹן שֶׁהָיָה אָבִיו גֵּר וְנָשָׂא גִּיּוֹרֶת, אֲפִלּוּ הָכִי מֻתָּר בְּמַמְזֶרֶת, וְדַוְקָא עַד עֲשָׂרָה דּוֹרוֹת, אֲבָל מִכָּאן וְאֵילָךְ אָסוּר, שֶׁכְּבָר נִשְׁתַּקַּע מִמֶּנּוּ שֵׁם גֵּרוּת, וְיָבוֹאוּ לוֹמַר: יִשְׂרָאֵל נוֹשֵׂא מַמְזֶרֶת. וּלְהָרַמְבַּ''ם מֻתָּר בְּמַמְזֶרֶת, וְכֵן בֶּן בֶּן בְּנוֹ, עַד שֶׁיִּשְׁתַּקַּע שֵׁם גֵּרוּתוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ וְלֹא יִוָּדַע שֶׁהוּא גֵּר, וְאַחַר כָּךְ יֵאָסֵר בְּמַמְזֶרֶת. אֶחָד הַגֵּרִים וְאֶחָד הָעֲבָדִים הַמְשֻׁחְרָרִים, דִּין אֶחָד לְכֻלָּם: